# citation link for questions and answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

I'm sure everybody is familiar with [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/). But do you know that they have for each question and answer a "cite" link that opens up a window with a bibtex citation? I'm using them right now and they're great!!

Can we have something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already implemented. If you click on the 'link' reference, and then on the 'cite' link in the blue box (to the bottom right of the URL), you'll get the bibtex entry. This was in fact inspired by mathoverflow's cite code.

Comment: arrggh, didn't know that, thanks!!